# Arduino for TTL triggering: trigger received as soon as pinmode is defined

Tags: arduino

I've got an Arduino Uno with a shield from Zaber (X-AS01). I use one of the digital outputs from the shield to provide a 5V trigger signal (when 5V signal is received by the connected device, data acquisition starts).

However, as soon as my script is uploaded, the external device registers a trigger signal although I have not put the pin to HIGH. This behaviour is happening as soon as I declare the pinmode of the corresponding pin (see code below).

When I upload another script defining other pins and triggering them, my data acquisition device is nicely showing "waiting for trigger signal".

```cpp
/*
Start data acquisition
*/

int acquisition = 6; // the pin data aquisition system is connected to

void setup() {
  pinMode(acquisition, OUTPUT); // Declare pin as an output
}

void loop(){
  //
}
```

Comment: what edge are you triggering on?

Comment: try to set pin HIGH before pinMode

Comment: @Juraj: This worked! Perfect, Thank you so much, what an easy fix.

Comment: you device is active on LOW state on signal pin

Answer (score 0):

Lacking any further information by best guess is that you're either triggering to some noise or to the falling edge that you will likely observe when you turn the pinmode to OUTPUT.

> However, as soon as my script is uploaded, the external device
> registers a trigger signal although I have not put the pin to HIGH.

Uploading the code involves a reset of the microcontroller.
The digital pins default to INPUT on reset. That means their state is floating. Rising or falling edges might occur at any time due to noise. Once you turn them into OUTPUTs their state defaults to LOW. Possibly causing a falling edge.

I would use a pulldown resistor on the trigger pin. That way your signal is low until you set the output state HIGH

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good point. I tried to find out how to achieve this: does it mean to split the cable coming from the output pin and connect one to the arduino ground via a resistor (10kOhm?) ?